# A word that describes "can't wait" in the following sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I'm trying to find a word to fit in this sentence:

- “The kid was waiting _______ for his present”

Answer (score 2):

"**eagerly**" probably would be the best choice here.

Answer (score 1):

If you just can't wait for something to happen, you're being impatient:

> The kid was waiting **impatiently** for his present.
>
> She is waiting **impatiently** for her husband's return.

Answer (score 0):

'Excitedly' would be a word you could use.

Or 'on tenterhooks' - nervously anticipating something. Keen to have the outcome.

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/tenterhook